# What is this kind of style?

Tags: style-identification, style

I would know what kind of style is the following image to make further research please, from the web I have seen they talk abut grunge style, but I can t find more information about the technique, 
here an example:

[image: enter image descripktion here]

any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific name, but I guess you could call it a grunge paint texture. I think it's meant to look a bit like an impressionistic/grungy watercolour illustration.

In my opinion, it has almost certainly been done digitally in Photoshop (or similar raster image editor), starting with a photograph of a street scene, and with the use of a layer mask to reveal photographs of paint textures.

Here's a rough idea of how it could be done

Get a photograph of a street scene, desaturate it, and apply a threshold adjustment. Invert it, and paint in black around the edges with a paint stroke type brush.

Then apply the Cutout filter

Here's a before and after which shows what you should end up with:

[image]

Next, find two paint texture photographs (or take your own!)

Create a layered composition, using the black and white image you already created as a layer mask on one of the paint textures. Basically this will mask out one paint texture layer, and reveal the other paint texture layer below.

Like this

[image]
Better quality example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wkLa.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

There is a trend called "Glitch"... but there is not only one kind of glitch, but it is a start.

That also reminds me of some sort of "solarization".

Answer (score 2):

While typically more relative to tattoo artwork...

I'd call this [**Trash-Polka**](https://www.google.com/search?q=trash%20polka&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdnbPBtd7hAhUJj1QKHWgLBj0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1413&bih=1235), ([2](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/862017184900260804/)) if anything.

> [image]
>    <sub>artwork by "[TATJACK](https://www.pinterest.se/pin/512284526361189277/)"</sub>

Trash polka tattoos typically stick to red and black for coloring, but the overall style is very similar.